# Formal argument for why $(\mathbb{Z}/(4))_{(2)} = \mathbb{Z}/(4)$

Tags: commutative-algebra

I'm learning about localizations, and I came across this statement:
$$ \left(\mathbb{Z}/(4)\right)_{(2)} = \mathbb{Z}/(4) $$
Now, this statement makes sense because inverting all of the odd elements have no effect since the images of odd elements in $\mathbb{Z}/(4)$ are all invertible. But I'm struggling to write this down formally, what exactly can I write down to convince myself of this fact beyond a reasonable doubt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complement of $(2)$ is the set of all units of $\mathbb{Z}/(4)$.

Comment: So, if $I$ is an ideal of $R$ and $P$ is a prime ideal of $R$, then when we write $(R/I)_{P}$ do we actually mean the homomorphic image of $P$ under the quotient map?

Comment: Probably, since $P$ doesn't live in $(R/I) $.